# Split expression into list of terms

Tags: list-manipulation, expression-manipulation

I'm looking for a nice way to split an expression into a list of the terms (i.e. the addends).

The desired behavior in:

```
terms[a^2 + a^-2 + c]  
(* Out: {a^2, a^-2, c} *)
terms[a*b*c]
(* Out: {a*b*c} *)
```

I've tried a few solutions. MonomialList doesn't work if the expression is not a polynomial. I've also tried

```
Level[a + b + c, 1]
(* Out: {a, b, c} *)
```

But the problem is it breaks down for monomials.

```
Level[a, 1]
(* Out: {} *)
Level[a*b*c, 1]
(* Out: {a, b, c} *)
```

The desired output would be `{a}` and `{a b c}` respectively.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `terms[a*b*c]` but terms here are `a` and `b` and `c`.  Unless you are using your own definition of what a `term` is.  So  you can use `List @@ expr ` to obtain the terms. `expr = a^2 + a^-2 + c; List @@ expr ` gives `{1/a^2, a^2, c}` and `expr = a*b*c; List @@ expr ` gives `{a, b, c}` etc..

Comment: @Nasser Thank you for your reply. To clarify, I am using "term" to mean addend. I am finding that the ` List @@ expr ` similarly does not handle monomials correctly. Namely `expr = a; List @@ expr` returns just `a` rather than `{a}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Applying new Heads

Mathematica has a [built-in function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) for applying a specific *head* in an expression. Both of these are (almost) equivalent:

```
Apply[List, expr]
List@@expr
```

### Baby Steps and Single Use Cases

`Apply` replaces a *head(s)* in an expression with the specified *head*. The default *levelspec* is `{0}`, meaning it only applies to the top level (the `Head` of `expr` itself) when you don't specify anything else.

[image: List applied to 2 expressions]

When using the [curried form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) (`List@@expr`), `expr` is evaluated before applying your specified `head`. Parentheses help protect you from this.

*(Note that this first one is evaluated as* `(List@@a)+b+c` *and* `a` *has no head to replace.)*

[image: Examples of the curried form of Apply]

Alternatively, to be certain what you're applying your new *head* to, you could `Defer` evaluation, but then you need use the curried form of `MapApply` (`@@@`) to Apply `List` to the expression inside `Defer`, not to `Defer` itself.

[image: MapApply is needed when you Defer evaluation]

## Writing A Function To Do This

To do this right, we need something stronger than `Defer`. We'll need `Hold` and `ReleaseHold`.

### Extracting Only Addition Terms

It's easy to use `Apply` to replace the top level *head* with `List`. It's still relatively easy to selectively replace `Plus` with `List` when it's the level 0 head. Handling the monomials (when the *head* is not `Plus`) is a larger challenge.

- If the *head* is `Plus`, you want it replaced with `List`
- If the *head* is not `Plus`, you want to wrap `List` around the expression

Without building `If` into the function, it's tricky to satisfy both conditions at the same time. Most attempts to satisfy one condition gave one too many or one too few instances of `List` in the other case.

It took quite a bit of debugging, but the solution is to wrap everything in `List`, then if `Plus` is the unevaluated *head*, replace it with `Sequence`. This always applies `List`, and if we have `Plus`, we get rid of it and just pass its sequence of parameters into the outer list, without creating a second list. Because we need wrap `Hold` around everything, we now need `Extract` to get at the buried `Plus`.

### Summary

1. Use `HoldAll` to ensure everything comes into the function without modification
2. Wrap everything in `Hold` to prevent modification while working with the expression
3. Reach past `Hold` and `Extract` the original *head*
4. If that *head* is `Plus`, replace it with `Sequence`
5. Take this *head* and `Apply` it back inside the held expression
6. `ReleaseHold`
7. Put everything inside `List`

   - `Sequence` will absorb into `List` and disappear, any other *head* will remain

You need both these lines to make it work.

```
SetAttributes[terms, HoldAll]
terms[expr_] := {ReleaseHold[Apply[Replace[Extract[Hold[expr], {1, 0}], Plus -> Sequence], Hold[expr], {1}]]}
```

### Examples

The `FullForm` column shows that there aren't any spare `Hold`, `Defer`, or `Unevaluated` floating around.

[image: Examples]

Answer (score 13):

```
ClearAll[terms]
SetAttributes[terms, HoldAll]
terms[Plus[a__]] := {a}
terms[a_?AtomQ] := {a}
terms[a_] := a
```

***Examples:***

```
ClearAll[a, b, c, d]

terms[a]
```

> {a}

```
terms[a + b + c]
```

> {a, b, c}

```
terms[a b c]
```

> a b c

```
terms[a^2 + a^-2 + c]
```

> {a^2, 1/a^2, c}

```
terms[a b c + 3 Sin[c + d] + Log@d]
```

> {a b c, 3 Sin[c + d], Log[d]}

Comment: This works perfectly! I appreciate you putting in the effort.

Comment: @mwalth, you are welcome. And welcome to mma.se.

Comment: As always: cool answer from you!

Comment: But when I write `u=a+b` and `terms[u]` your function does not work. Do you know how to generalize?

Comment: @yarchik, you can use `terms[Evaluate@u]` ?

Comment: @yarchik or remove the `HoldAll` attribute.

Answer (score 5):

For the examples you mentioned, the following simple replacement works:

```
a^2 + a^-2 + c /. Plus -> List

(* Out: {1/a^2, a^2, c} *)
```

Note that the ordering is not retained, but then you probably shouldn't depend on the order of monomials anyway because MMA might rewrite your expression on its own to conform to its "canonical" format (e.g. evaluating `b - a` returns `-a + b`).

Similarly,

```
a*b*c /. Plus -> List     (* Out: a*b*c *)
a /. Plus -> List         (* Out: a     *)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! This seems to work well for expressions with multiple expressions, but I'm finding that `abc /. Plus->List` returns `abc` whereas I would hope for it to return the singleton list `{abc}`. Do you know how to modify so that it returns a list regardless of the number of terms in the input?

Answer (score 1):

No sure whether I got your point, but you can do something like (o.k. broth-force attack ;-) ):

```
    makeList[term_] := 
 ToExpression /@ StringSplit[ToString[term, InputForm], "+"
   ]
```

then

```
temp = a^2 + a^-2 + c
```

and

```
makeList@temp
```

yields:

```
{1/a^2, a^2, c}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. This was a route I thought about going also. I realize I didn't specify this in the question, but I also need it to split terms that have a minus "-"  in addition to a plus "+". Do you know if this is possible with your method?

Comment: You can use `StringSplit[term,{"+","-"}]` this should work

Comment: Very good, thank you!